# How to use count() correlated sub select

Tags: sql, count, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have this SQL query

```
SELECT table1.* 
  FROM table1 table1 
 WHERE table1.table2_id IN (SELECT table2.id 
                              FROM table2 
                             WHERE table2.locked = 0)
```

I get the result and it works fine, but now I want to count how many rows exist.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT table1.count(*) 
  FROM table1 table1 
 WHERE table1.table2_id IN (SELECT table2.id 
                              FROM table2 
                             WHERE table2.locked = 0)
```

But nothing worked…

**How can I count the rows in this kind of query?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table1 table1
WHERE table1.`table2_id` IN (SELECT table2.id FROM table2 WHERE table2.locked = 0)
```

Hope it will help you! ..